# How to generate a CSS unicode-range from a font file

Tags: css, unicode, webfonts

How can I automatically generate a `unicode-range` from a font file? I'd want it to detect all unicode ranges or single unicode numbers where glyphs exist in that font. e.g:

```
unicode-range: U+0102-0103, U+0110-0111, U+0128-0129, U+01A0-01A1, U+20AB;
```

Currently I have to open the font file in an analyzer (either web based or desktop app) and figure out the ranges manually.